# Can I get a trait object of a multi-trait instance without using a generic type?

Tags: rust

I am trying to get a dynamically dispatchable borrow to an instance of an object implementing both `Reader` and `Seek`.

I understand that Rust can do dynamic dispatch as long as there is only one trait involved.

```
use std::io::{Read, Seek};
fn user(stream: &mut Read) {}
```

With two or more trait bounds though, I am forced to use a type parameter:

```
fn user_gen<T: Read + Seek>(stream: &mut T) {}
```

As the actual type underneath is a builder, it would have to store the borrowed object in some way, and using a type parameter for this would make the implementation more complex (I have three type parameters already).

Ideally, I would be able to do something like that:

```
fn user_dynamic(stream: &mut (Read + Seek)) {}
```

This does not compile:

```
error[E0225]: only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object
 --> src/main.rs:3:38
  |
3 | fn user_dynamic(stream: &mut (Read + Seek)) {}
  |                                      ^^^^ non-auto additional trait
```

I understand that dynamic dispatch is done through fat pointers, and usually these only refer to one method table, not to multiple ones. I have not seen a statically compiled language that would support this, but such a feature would help me a lot.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can create an empty trait that merges those two traits:

```
use std::io::{Read, Seek};

trait SeekRead: Seek + Read {}
impl<T: Seek + Read> SeekRead for T {}

fn user_dynamic(stream: &mut SeekRead) {}
```

This will create a new vtable for `SeekRead` that contains all the function pointers of both `Seek` and `Read`.

You will not be able to cast your `&mut SeekRead` to either `&mut Seek` or `&mut Read` without some trickery (see [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632968/why-doesnt-rust-support-trait-object-upcasting))