# Are the different ways to combine traits in Rust equivalent?

Tags: inheritance, rust, traits

There are two ways to "combine traits" in Rust, I believe. I'm wondering what the differences are.

To be concrete, let's say the two traits are `Beeps` and `Honks`

```
trait Beeps { fn beep(&self); }
trait Honks { fn honk(&self); }
```

A new empty trait can be formed, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897297/can-i-get-a-trait-object-of-a-multi-trait-instance-without-using-a-generic-type):

```
impl<T: Beeps + Honks> BeepsAndHonks for T {}
```

For concreteness, an implementation would just be this:

```
struct Obj {}
impl Beeps for Obj { fn beep(&self) {} }
impl Honks for Obj { fn honk(&self) {} }
```

The combined trait can be used like so

```
fn factory() -> Box<dyn BeepsAndHonks> {
    Box::new( Obj {} )
}
```

The other way to achieve a "combined trait" is via [suptertraits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/supertraits.html):

```
trait BeepsAndHonks2: Beeps { fn honk(&self); }
```

This uses `Beeps` as a base and layers a `honk` on top. (Sorry for all the silly beeping and honking.)

When I don't own `Beeps` and `Honks` then the new empty trait is the only way to do this (I believe). Otherwise I can do either new empty trait or supertrait. Structurally the two approaches are different, but under the hood there is no difference, e.g. regarding number of vtable lookups, is that correct?

Since traits clearly can be combined, what speaks against allowing the `Beeps+Honks` syntax, e.g. `fn factory() -> Box<dyn Beeps+Honks>`?

Comment: One thing I just noticed: There are [Object Safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) requirements for base traits. For example, it seems that `Iterator` does not fulfill these requirements.

Comment: Note that there is a third option, that you didn't mention, which may fit your requirements. See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0e24cfe5bd8c4727ea1114784b0222e). It's a combination of your two solutions.

Comment: There are trait aliases `trait Trait2 = Trait0 + Trait1;`, but they’re not suitable for trait objects. The best way is to create a supertrait `trait Trait2: Trait0 + Trait1 {}` `impl<T: Trait0 + Trait1> Trait2 for T {}`

Comment: @jthulhu Yes I see. Now it's even less clear to me whether these are just three different ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two ways are not equivalent. Let's see what different options actually mean:

### Generic implementation of supertrait

Your first example:

```rust
trait Beeps { fn beep(&self); }
trait Honks { fn honk(&self); }

trait BeepsAndHonks {}
impl<T: Beeps + Honks> BeepsAndHonks for T {}

struct Obj {}
impl Beeps for Obj { fn beep(&self) {} }
impl Honks for Obj { fn honk(&self) {} }
```

Here you provide implementation of the `BeepsAndHonks` trait for any trait that have both `Beeps` and `Honks` type. This is convenient not have to write implementation for every such type, but note that you can have a type implementing `BeepsAndHonks` that cannot neither beep nor honk:

```rust
struct AnotherObj {}
impl BeepsAndHonks for AnotherObj {}
```

### Supertraiting `Honks`

Your second example:

```
trait BeepsAndHonks2: Beeps { fn honk(&self); }
```

is different from the first. In this case you can have a type a that implements `Beeps` or both `Beeps` and `Honks` together, but not only `Honks` as allowed by the first example.

### Supertrait with bounds

You can prevent the problem in the first example by requiring `BeepsAndHonks` to also implement related traits:

```rust
trait BeepsAndHonks: Beeps + Honks {}
```

Now `AnotherObj` cannot exist. If you add `Beeps` and `Honks` implementations for it, it will have two conflicting implementaions of `BeepsAndHonks` (one manual and one generic from the first example). And if your don't provide them trait bounds are not satisfied.