# Is there a Rust signature signaling that any type that coerces into T would be allowed?

Tags: rust, nested, dereference, coercion

So I just started learning about Rust and the Implicit Deref Coercion. A "problem" I now often tumble over, is that this automatic deref does not work inside of other types, e.g. as Item types of collections. In the following [example (sandbox)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d09625d065ee3345419ce72487deb8bc), what changes can be done in the function signature, to make the last line in `main` work, or is there no other way than do the conversion outside of the function call explicitly?

```rust
fn find_in_vec<T>(v: Vec<T>) -> bool
where
    T: AsRef<str>
{
    for e in v {
        if e.as_ref() == "hello" {
            return true;
        }
    }
    false
}

fn is_hello(s: &str) -> bool {
    s == "hello"
}

fn main() {
    let h1: &str = "hello";
    let h2: &String = &"hi".to_string();
    let h3: &Box<String> = &Box::new("hi".to_string());
    println!("{}", is_hello(h1));  // works
    println!("{}", is_hello(h2));  // works
    println!("{}", is_hello(h3));  // works

    let a: Vec<&str> = vec!["hello", "world", "!"];
    let b: Vec<&str> = vec!["hallo", "world", "!"];
    let chelp = "hello".to_string();
    let c: Vec<&String> = vec![&chelp];
    let d: Vec<&Box<String>> = vec![&Box::new("hello".to_string())];
    println!("{}", find_in_vec(a));  // works
    println!("{}", find_in_vec(b));  // works
    println!("{}", find_in_vec(c));  // works
    println!("{}", find_in_vec(d));  // fails
}
```

Compile Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Box<String>: AsRef<str>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:33:32
   |
33 |     println!("{}", find_in_vec(d));
   |                    ----------- ^ the trait `AsRef<str>` is not implemented for `Box<String>`
   |                    |
   |                    required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `AsRef<T>` is implemented for `Box<T, A>`
   = note: required for `&Box<String>` to implement `AsRef<str>`
note: required by a bound in `find_in_vec`
```

Any insights on idiomatic ways to solve/work around/avoid this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I know that the `Box<String>` is overkill in this example, just consider it a minimal example. In my "real" world, I don't have boxed Strings but a list of pointers to different structs all having the same Trait, e.g. `Box<dyn MyTrait>`.

Comment: `Box<String>` is kind of a nonsense type. `String` is already heap-allocated, so why box it?

Comment: As pointed out, you are better off getting rid of those `Box<String>`, as they are inefficient and may bring more difficulties integrating with generic code.

Comment: Thanks for your fast responses. The Box was a deliberate example, as I already experimented with `AsRef` but did not fully grasp it yet, so I did not include it in my first post. I modified the example now, considering the duplicate-linked questions, using AsRef, showing that it actually works with a plain `String`. However, because the `Box<String>` needs to chain 2 derefs, which in automatic deref coercion works, however, it still does not work in this case. Please reconsider my question as open.

Comment: @E_net4 could you help me reopen this question or give further clarifications regarding my comment and edit of the question, why you still might think it is a duplicate? If the issue is really the Box in `Box<dyn MyTrait>` is there something better I can use in generic functions?

Comment: Do the values inside the `Box` also implement `AsRef<str>`? In that case, you may be able to extend or create a new trait to include both requirements in your trait object (https://stackoverflow.com/q/28897297), so that it provides the behaviour of both `MyTrait` and `AsRef<str>`. Please see if this works.