# Is it possible to 'downcast' a trait object in a closure argument?

Tags: rust

I'd like to invoke a function pointer which itself takes a trait object as an argument:

```
fn invoke(x: &Fn(&WithFoo), y: &MyStruct) {
    // MyStruct implements WithFoo
    x(y);
}
```

So far so good. Now, what I'm having trouble with is how to call this with a function pointer with signature such as `&Fn(&WithFooBar)` where the trait `WithFooBar` inherits from `WithFoo`.

Here is my sample code where I attempt to do this:

```
trait WithFoo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

trait WithFooBar: WithFoo {
    fn bar(&self);
}

struct MyStruct {
}

impl WithFoo for MyStruct {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("foo");
    }
}

impl WithFooBar for MyStruct {
    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("bar");
    }
}

fn foobar_caller(wf: &WithFooBar) {
    wf.foo();
    wf.bar();
}

fn invoke(x: &Fn(&WithFoo), y: &MyStruct) {
    x(y);
}

fn main() {
    let data = MyStruct {};
    invoke(&foobar_caller,&data);
}
```

This fails with the following compile error:

```
error: type mismatch: the type `fn(&WithFooBar) {foobar_caller}` implements the trait `for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(&'r WithFooBar + 'r,)>`, but the trait `for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(&'r WithFoo + 'r,)>` is required (expected trait `WithFoo`, found trait `WithFooBar`) [--explain E0281]
```

I understand that the error is saying that `&Fn(&WithFooBar)` is not `&Fn(&WithFoo)`, but given that the `WithFooBar` trait inherits from `WithFoo`, is seems like it should be possible to pass a pointer to this function.

Is it possible to somehow "downcast" the function pointer to type `&Fn(&WithFoo)`? I have tried both this:

```
 let f = &foobar_caller as &Fn(&WithFoo);
 invoke(f,&data);
```

and this:

```
 let f: &Fn(&WithFoo) = &foobar_caller;
 invoke(f,&data);
```

But neither of these attempts works.

(This example is on the rust playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=trait%20WithFoo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20foo(%26self)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20WithFooBar%3A%20WithFoo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20bar(%26self)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20MyStruct%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20WithFoo%20for%20MyStruct%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20foo(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22foo%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20WithFooBar%20for%20MyStruct%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20bar(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22bar%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20foobar_caller(wf%3A%20%26WithFooBar)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wf.foo()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wf.bar()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20invoke(x%3A%20%26Fn(%26WithFoo)%2C%20y%3A%20%26MyStruct)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x(y)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20MyStruct%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20invoke(%26foobar_caller%2C%26data)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=nightly&backtrace=0).)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632968/why-doesnt-rust-support-trait-object-upcasting .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this. First off, Rust doesn't support downcasting a trait object to another trait object. With the `Any` trait, you could downcast a trait object to the underlying object's concrete type and then get a trait object for a different type, but that requires knowing the object's concrete type, which you don't know – that's the whole point of trait objects!

Furthermore, what you're trying to do is not sound: a function expecting to receive a `&WithFooBar` should not be passed a `&WithFoo`, because the `WithFoo` might not implement `WithFooBar`. If it was the other way around though, it would be sound, but even though `WithFooBar` inherits from `WithFoo`, Rust doesn't allow casting a `&WithFooBar` to a `&WithFoo`, so even if we tried to make a wrapper function, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks, the hint about `Any` worked for me, as I do actually know the object's concrete type.