# Downcasting Rust Trait Combinations

Tags: types, polymorphism, rust

I have two structs, `Dog` and `Cat`:

```
struct Dog {
    weight: f64
}
struct Cat {
    weight: f64
}
```

and two traits `MakesSound` and `HasWeight`

```
trait MakesSound {
    fn make_sound(&self);
}

impl MakesSound for Dog {
    fn make_sound(&self) {
        println!("Bark bark!");
    }
}

impl MakesSound for Cat {
    fn make_sound(&self) {
        println!("Go away.");
    }
}

trait HasWeight {
    fn get_weight(&self) -> f64;
}

impl HasWeight for Dog {
    fn get_weight(&self) -> f64 { self.weight }
}

impl HasWeight for Cat {
    fn get_weight(&self) -> f64 { self.weight }
}
```

I would like to be able to store them in a heterogeneous `Vec` and then make use of both their traits

```
trait Animal: MakesSound + HasWeight {}
impl<T: MakesSound + HasWeight> Animal for T {}

fn main() {
    let dog = Dog{ weight: 45.0 };
    let cat = Cat{ weight: 12.0 };
    let animals: Vec<&Animal> = vec![&dog, &cat];
    for animal in animals {
        animal.make_sound();
        println!("{}", animal.get_weight());
        //print_weight(animal as &HasWeight);
    }
}
```

How would I define a `print_weight` function that had type

```
fn print_weight(x: &HasWeight);
```

so that my function would require as little information as possible, but my `Vec` is storing as much information as possible?

The error I get from uncommenting the line above is

```
error: non-scalar cast: `&Animal` as `&HasWeight`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632968/why-doesnt-rust-support-trait-object-upcasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `print_weight` function that is generic over types with the `HasWeight` trait. Unfortunately, I'm too inexperienced with Rust to tell you why the additional `?Sized` trait bound is necessary.

```
fn print_weight<T: HasWeight + ?Sized>(thing: &T) {
    println!("{}", thing.get_weight());
}
```

This can be called from within your loop without any casting: `print_weight(animal)`.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23%5Bderive(Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20Dog%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20weight%3A%20f64%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20Cat%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20weight%3A%20f64%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20MakesSound%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20make_sound(%26self)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20MakesSound%20for%20Dog%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20make_sound(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Bark%20bark!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20MakesSound%20for%20Cat%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20make_sound(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Go%20away.%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20HasWeight%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20get_weight(%26self)%20-%3E%20f64%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20HasWeight%20for%20Dog%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20get_weight(%26self)%20-%3E%20f64%20%7B%20self.weight%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20HasWeight%20for%20Cat%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20get_weight(%26self)%20-%3E%20f64%20%7B%20self.weight%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20Animal%3A%20MakesSound%20%2B%20HasWeight%20%7B%7D%0Aimpl%3CT%3A%20MakesSound%20%2B%20HasWeight%3E%20Animal%20for%20T%20%7B%7D%0A%0Afn%20print_weight%3CT%3A%20HasWeight%20%2B%20%3FSized%3E(thing%3A%20%26T)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20thing.get_weight())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20dog%20%3D%20Dog%7B%20weight%3A%2045.0%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20cat%20%3D%20Cat%7B%20weight%3A%2012.0%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20animals%3A%20Vec%3C%26Animal%3E%20%3D%20vec!%5B%26dog%2C%20%26cat%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20animal%20in%20animals%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20animal.make_sound()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print_weight(animal)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: That does indeed work although... I thought the Sized trait was a requirement, that the compiler can be shut up by telling it that Sized is optional suggests that the compiler can do without it. I'd be interested to know how and if static dispatch is still occurring.

Comment: To address both of your concerns: the `?Sized` bound is required for mapping T to unsized types. In particular, when `T = HasWeight`, the function argument becomes a trait object (`&HasWeight`), which is dynamically dispatched. For other cases, the concrete object type behind the argument is known and this one would be statically dispatched.