# Using Any with traits in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to implement `PartialEq` in Rust for a trait that has subtypes, so that I can add them as boxed pointers to a container and later compare them.

Here's my scaled-down implementation:

```
use std::any::Any;

trait Foo: Any {}

struct Bar {}

impl Foo for Bar {}

struct Baz {}

impl Foo for Baz {}

impl PartialEq for Foo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Foo) -> bool {
        let me = self as &Any;
        let you = other as &Any;
        if me.is::<Bar>() && you.is::<Bar>() {
            true
        } else if me.is::<Baz>() && you.is::<Baz>() {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bar: Bar = Bar {};
    let baz: Baz = Baz {};
    let foo1: &Foo = &bar;
    let foo2: &Foo = &baz;
    println!("{:?}", foo1 == foo2);
}
```

[Code example in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Aany%3A%3AAny%3B%0A%0Atrait%20Foo%3A%20Any%20%7B%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Bar%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Foo%20for%20Bar%20%7B%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Baz%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Foo%20for%20Baz%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20PartialEq%20for%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20eq(%26self%2C%20other%3A%20%26Foo)%20-%3E%20bool%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20me%20%3D%20self%20as%20%26Any%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20you%20%3D%20other%20as%20%26Any%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20me.is%3A%3A%3CBar%3E()%20%26%26%20you.is%3A%3A%3CBar%3E()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20me.is%3A%3A%3CBaz%3E()%20%26%26%20you.is%3A%3A%3CBaz%3E()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20bar%3A%20Bar%20%3D%20Bar%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20baz%3A%20Baz%20%3D%20Baz%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo1%3A%20%26Foo%20%3D%20%26bar%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20foo2%3A%20%26Foo%20%3D%20%26baz%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20foo1%20%3D%3D%20foo2)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=nightly&backtrace=0).

When I build this, I get:

```
rustc 1.17.0-nightly (0648517fa 2017-02-03)
error: non-scalar cast: `&Foo + 'static` as `&std::any::Any + 'static`
  --> <anon>:15:18
   |
15 |         let me = self as &Any;
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: non-scalar cast: `&Foo + 'static` as `&std::any::Any + 'static`
  --> <anon>:16:19
   |
16 |         let you = other as &Any;
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

which is confusing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit**: I don't believe this is a duplicate of [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632968), because what I'm trying to do is downcast using `Any`, not upcast.

**Further Edit**: Yes, this is a duplicate - sorry, I was thinking about what I was trying to do (downcast to the `Bar` and `Baz` types) rather than how I was doing that (upcasting to `Any`). However, that being said, I guess I still don't understand why the [Any example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/), where they do this: `let value_any = value as &Any;` works, where mine doesn't. That being said, [Joshua Entrekin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3179290/joshua-entrekin) did give a great answer.

**Final Edit** An, never mind, it's because I'm upcasting a trait rather than a type - **Doh!**. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: I'm too new to the language to tell you all of your options, but it looks a bit like you're trying to do OO style sub-typing. Have you tried using an enum of some kind?

Comment: @JustinBlank Tried that, but there's nowhere to put the num AFAICT - you can't add an enum to a trait, and if I make a global enum, it feels very kludgey. The docs for Any imply that if your type is an Any, you should be able to do the kind of casting I'm doing - hence my question.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense to me, and I'm thinking that there's a terminology difference. You are trying to convert a `&Foo` to an `&Any`, *going upward in the hierarchy*. That's upcasting. Why do you say you are trying to downcast? [@JoshuaEntrekin also provides an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3aae5b8349e3420497f3aa24f9e8ea7b&version=nightly&backtrace=0) that seems to work.

Comment: @Shepmaster Sorry, I commented on his response, but didn't update my post. See above.

Answer (score 13):

This is a duplicate of [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632968/why-doesnt-rust-support-trait-object-upcasting) because you are trying to upcast from `Foo` to `Any`. If you add an `as_any` method to `Foo` and implement on it, this code can be made to work:

```
use std::any::Any;

trait Foo: Any {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any;
}

impl<T: Any> Foo for T {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any {
        self
    }
}

struct Bar {}

struct Baz {}

impl PartialEq for Foo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Foo) -> bool {
        let me = self.as_any();
        let you = other.as_any();
        if me.is::<Bar>() && you.is::<Bar>() {
            true
        } else if me.is::<Baz>() && you.is::<Baz>() {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bar: Bar = Bar {};
    let baz: Baz = Baz {};
    let foo1: &Foo = &bar;
    let foo2: &Foo = &baz;
    println!("{:?}", foo1 == foo2);
}
```

I show it here in the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3aae5b8349e3420497f3aa24f9e8ea7b&version=nightly&backtrace=0).

Comment: Thank you very much for doing the right thing and pointing out the duplicate. I hope you hang around [tag:rust] and help identify more dupes, and maybe have the chance to answer some non-duplicates too! ^_^

Comment: Trait objects without an explicit `dyn` is a hard error in Rust 2021. Therefore here the updated [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e399193db4c5b5ef22d4ff38e73a2bc9).