# Under which conditions is Box<dyn T> coerced to &dyn T?

Tags: rust

Backstory: I'm writing a simple interpreter following a tutorial for fun. At some point I need to check if the thing in `Box<dyn Expr>` is `Variable` (which impls `Expr`). I follow the `as_any` pattern described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056422/using-any-with-traits-in-rust).

In a test like this:

```rust
let e: Box<dyn Expr> = Box::new(Variable{ 
        name: Token{ token_type: TokenType::Number, lexeme: "123".to_string(), literal: Some(LoxValue::Number(123f64)), line: 1 } 
    });
assert!(e.as_any().is::<Variable>());
assert!(e.as_any().downcast_ref::<Variable>().is_some());
```

The assertions succeed.

They work as expected. And rust analyzer tells me that:

```
Type Box<dyn Expr, Global> Coerced to: &dyn Expr
```

While this behavior is what I would expect and convenient, somehow I cannot reproduce it in another place. I must write `(*the_box).as_any().is::<SomeStruct>()` to do the same thing, or the check always returns false.

The definetions:

```rust
pub trait AsAny: Any {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

impl<T: Any> AsAny for T  {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

pub trait Expr: AsAny + Debug{
    fn evaluate(&self, environment: &mut Environment) -> EvaluateResult;
    fn boxed(self) -> Box<dyn Expr> where Self: Sized {
        Box::new(self)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Variable {
    pub name: Token,
}

impl Expr for Variable {
    fn evaluate(&self, environment: &mut Environment) -> super::expr::EvaluateResult {
        environment.get(self.name.clone())
    }
}
```

However, if I write something like this in a fresh new package:

```rust
trait AsAny: Any {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

impl<T: Any> AsAny for T  {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

struct Foo  {}

trait TheTrait: AsAny {}

impl TheTrait for Foo {}

fn main() {
    let b: Box<dyn TheTrait> = Box::new(Foo{});
    println!("{}", b.as_any().is::<Foo>());
    println!("{}", (*b).as_any().is::<Foo>());
}
```

Only the second line of `println!` prints true.

---

**UPDATE**: It's weird. It seems that `(*boxed_thing).as_any().is::<SomeThing>()` should be the correct way to do this.

Maybe there has been some kind of bug (I am not sure whose bug it is) which makes `boxed_thing.as_any().is::<Something>()` work.

I copied all the source files into a new place and the assertions failed.

Comment: Can you provide a working and a non-working example function that we can compile and run ourselves that demonstrates the problem? Better would be two `#[test]` functions, one that fails and one that succeeds.

Comment: ot: `.is::<Variable>()` followed by `.downcast_ref::<Variable>()` seems odd, unless there is a specific reason you can use `if let Some(variable) = expr.as_any().downcast_ref::<Variable>()`.

Comment: @cafce25 tbh I did not really write something like that (not calling them one by one). Those two lines are just for example trying to demonstrate how I call the methods on Any.

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules

Answer (score 1):

This happens on `deref` method call of `Deref` trait which is inserted by the compiler in case of:

- field or method access via dot operator
- a deref coercion
- an explicit coercion via `&*box`