# "Subclassing" traits in Rust

Tags: rust, polymorphism, traits

I have a situation where several of my structs should implement multiple traits, but all of them implement at least one trait in common.  When I get hold of a mixed bag of these structs, I want to treat them all as being of the common trait: pass them as method parameters typed to that trait, store them in collections typed for that trait, etc.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.  Here is some code where I try to do the way it was suggested here, but it fails to compile:

```
trait ThingWithKeys {
    fn use_keys (&self) -> String;
}

//////

trait CorrectionsOfficer {
    fn hitch_up_pants (&self) -> String;
}

trait CorrectionsOfficerWithKeys: ThingWithKeys + CorrectionsOfficer {}

struct CorrectionsOfficerReal {}

impl ThingWithKeys for CorrectionsOfficerReal {
    fn use_keys (&self) -> String {
        String::from ("Clank, clank")
    }
}

impl CorrectionsOfficer for CorrectionsOfficerReal {
    fn hitch_up_pants (&self) -> String {
        String::from ("Grunt")
    }
}

impl <T: ThingWithKeys + CorrectionsOfficer> CorrectionsOfficerWithKeys for T {}

//////

trait Piano {
    fn close_lid (&self) -> String;
}

trait PianoWithKeys: Piano + ThingWithKeys {}

struct PianoReal {}

impl ThingWithKeys for PianoReal {
    fn use_keys (&self) -> String {
        String::from ("Tinkle, tinkle")
    }
}

impl Piano for PianoReal {
    fn close_lid (&self) -> String {
        String::from ("Bang!")
    }
}

impl <T: ThingWithKeys + Piano> PianoWithKeys for T {}

//////

trait Florida {
    fn hurricane (&self) -> String;
}

trait FloridaWithKeys: ThingWithKeys + Florida {}

struct FloridaReal {}

impl ThingWithKeys for FloridaReal {
    fn use_keys (&self) -> String {
        String::from ("Another margarita, please")
    }
}

impl Florida for FloridaReal {
    fn hurricane (&self) -> String {
        String::from ("Ho-hum...")
    }
}

impl <T: ThingWithKeys + Florida> FloridaWithKeys for T {}

//////

fn main() {
    let corrections_officer_ref: &CorrectionsOfficerWithKeys = &CorrectionsOfficerReal {};
    let piano_ref: &PianoWithKeys = &PianoReal {};
    let florida_ref: &FloridaWithKeys = &FloridaReal {};

    use_keys (corrections_officer_ref);
    use_keys (piano_ref);
    use_keys (florida_ref);
}

fn use_keys (thing_with_keys: &ThingWithKeys) {
    println! ("{}", thing_with_keys.use_keys ());
}
```

Here are the compilation errors:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (file:///playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:80:19
   |
80 |         use_keys (corrections_officer_ref);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait `ThingWithKeys`, found trait `CorrectionsOfficerWithKeys`
   |
   = note: expected type `&ThingWithKeys`
              found type `&CorrectionsOfficerWithKeys`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:81:19
   |
81 |         use_keys (piano_ref);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^ expected trait `ThingWithKeys`, found trait `PianoWithKeys`
   |
   = note: expected type `&ThingWithKeys`
              found type `&PianoWithKeys`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:82:19
   |
82 |         use_keys (florida_ref);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait `ThingWithKeys`, found trait `FloridaWithKeys`
   |
   = note: expected type `&ThingWithKeys`
              found type `&FloridaWithKeys`

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

Essentially, it still can't find the ThingWithKeys implementation inside the XxxWithKeys implementations.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Trait inheritance in Rust differs from OOP inheritance. Trait inheritance is just a way to specify requirements. `trait B: A` *does not imply* that if a type implements `B` it will automatically implement `A`;  it means that if a type implements `B` it *must implement* `A`. This also means that you will have to implement `A` *separately* if `B` is implemented.

As an example,

```
trait A {}
trait B: A {}

struct S;

impl B for S {}

// Commenting this line will result in a "trait bound unsatisfied" error
impl A for S {}

fn main() {
    let _x: &B = &S;
}
```

However, if want a type to automatically implement `C` if it implements `A` and `B` (and thereby avoiding manually implementing `C` for that type), then you can use a generic `impl`:

```
impl<T: A + B> C for T {}
```

In your example, this translates to

```
impl<T: Florida + ThingWithKeys> FloridaWithKeys for T {}
```

Take a look at [this forum thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/extending-traits/1802/8) for more information.

As an aside, you do not require the `ThingWithKeys` bound for `PianoWithKeys` as `Piano` already requires `ThingWithKeys`.

**EDIT** (in accordance with your comment and question edit):

As stated before, *trait inheritance in Rust differs from OOP inheritance.* Even if `trait B: A`, you cannot coerce a trait object of `B` to a trait object of `A`. If you have no other choice but to pass the trait objects as is to the method, using generics works:

```
fn use_keys<T: ThingWithKeys + ?Sized>(thing_with_keys: &T) {
    println! ("{}", thing_with_keys.use_keys ());
}
```

The generic method will work for type references (non trait objects) too.

Also check: [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632968/why-doesnt-rust-support-trait-object-upcasting)

Comment: Merry Christmas!  I tried it, just now, in the Playground, and it didn't seem to work.  Maybe I did it wrong.  I'd show you what I did, but StackOverflow does horrible things to the formatting of code in a comment.  Anyway, the upshot is that it still complains that a XxxWithKeys is not a ThingWithKeys and cannot be passed into the use_keys method.  (I know: I'll edit the original question instead to put my new code in.)

Comment: Wow.  I had actually just figured out the generic-method-signature thing and gotten the complaint about Sized, but I never in a million years would have thought to try + ?Sized, because it's a reference and references are all the same size.  Is there a good reason you need + ?Sized, or is it just a magical incantation you have to remember? (Thanks, by the way--it works fine now.)

Comment: That's because generic type parameters, by default, are `Sized`. Trait types, however, are not. To allow the type parameter to accept unsized (trait) types, you must add the unsized (`?Sized`) bound.

Comment: Also, the type parameter binds to the type of the reference, not the reference itself.