# How do I implement hierarchical traits?

Tags: rust

I have two traits in a hierarchy: `Animal` and `Bird`. How can I create a `Chicken` that implements `Bird`?

```
trait Animal {
    fn noise(&self) -> String;
    fn print_noise(&self) {
        print!("{}", self.noise());
    }
}

trait Bird: Animal {
    fn noise(&self) -> String {
        "chirp"
    }
}

struct Chicken {}

impl Bird for Chicken {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=88cbb993ecbd242740cb20fde37120b7)

When I try to compile, I get:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Chicken: Animal` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:16:6
   |
16 | impl Bird for Chicken {}
   |      ^^^^ the trait `Animal` is not implemented for `Chicken`
```

I don't want to implement `Animal` before `Bird`, because I want `Chicken` to inherit the `noise` function from `Bird`.

Comment: *to inherit the noise function from `Bird`*. Who is going to implement `Animal::noise`? It's **not** the same method as `Bird::noise`.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [“Subclassing” traits in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47965967/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: You should also go back and re-read [Object Oriented Programming Features of Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-00-oop.html) in *The Rust Programming Language*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't. Rust doesn't have inheritance by design.
Rust doesn't have same object-oriented model as Java or C++.

If you really want to do something like this, you can implement one trait for another with [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=386ba2d41a16ea896b798a7a4782b13f) code

```
trait Animal {
    fn noise(&self) -> String;
    fn print_noise(&self) {
        print!("{}", self.noise());
    }
}

trait Bird:Animal {}

impl<T: Bird> Animal for T {
    fn noise(&self) -> String {
        "chirp".to_string()
    }
}


struct Chicken {}

impl Bird for Chicken {}

fn main() {
    let chicken = Chicken{};
    chicken.print_noise();
}
```

As others, I would suggest reading [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) book, specifically [OOP](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch17-00-oop.html) and [Traits and Generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch10-00-generics.html) sections. It's free when reading online.

Comment: Does this answer mean you agree that the question has already been answered by the proposed duplicate?

Comment: @Shepmaster its 90% the same answer. However the proposed duplicate is more "multi-class" than "heirarchical-class" (if I'm understanding it correctly)