Require implementing either of trait methods
Is it possible to require trait implementations to implement only some of the methods for a trait?
In the below example, the method room_type has a default implementation based on the other methods, and the other methods have default implementations based on room_type.
Is there a way to require that either room_type has a custom implementation or all the other methods have one?
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum RoomType {
    Kitchen,
    LivingRoom,
    Bedroom,
}

pub trait House {
    fn room_type(&self) -> RoomType {
        if self.is_kitchen() {
            RoomType::Kitchen
        } else if self.is_living_room() {
            RoomType::LivingRoom
        } else {
            RoomType::Bedroom
        }
    }

    fn is_kitchen(&self) -> bool {
        self.room_type() == RoomType::Kitchen
    }

    fn is_living_room(&self) -> bool {
        self.room_type() == RoomType::LivingRoom
    }

    fn is_bedroom(&self) -> bool {
        self.room_type() == RoomType::Bedroom
    }
}


Are you asking if it is possible enforce at compile-time that a trait implementor must implement either a specific method or a group of other methods within the same trait?

yes, I'm wondering if it is possible at compile time.  Because if not, I'll have to decide when making the library what the users should implement, so that there's no risk of infinite recursion.  It won't be terrible, but just checking if it is possible to be more flexible.

I don't see a way of how this would be trivially possible with how Rust's trait structure is built.

I just spent time with docs. traits are just like interfaces , so I must say it is nearly impossible, I am afraid you would have to make a lib.

This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965967/subclassing-traits-in-rust. You can create multiple traits and implement default functions for each one to force your expected rule.

A situation similar to that arose with std::io::Read, where std wants to require implementing either of two methods, and the likely solution is to have some attribute #[rustc_implements_one_of] that enforces that, but unfortunately this is unlikely to be stabilized and will remain internal.

This is a pretty neat idea. There is precedent in Haskell, but currently it's not possible in Rust.
