# How to convert trait object to "sub-trait" object?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

This code:

```
trait A {}

trait B: A {}

struct S;

impl A for S {}

impl B for S {}

fn main() {
    let s = S;
    let trait_obj_b: &B = &s;
    let trait_obj_a: &A = trait_obj_b;
}
```

fails with the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:27
   |
14 |     let trait_obj_a: &A = trait_obj_b;
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait `A`, found trait `B`
   |
   = note: expected type `&A`
              found type `&B`
```

Why? Since `B` requires `A`, shouldn't all trait objects `&B` automatically implement `&A`? Is there a way to convert `&B` to `&A` without changing trait definitions or implementations?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=347946d23079ffab13503ce9296f2e7d&version=stable)

Comment: I believe your question is already answered by [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28632968/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the difference. Otherwise, we can mark this as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the link, I somehow missed it! Although the accepted answer is 3 years old, but if there is really no way to upcast trait objects without implementation modification, please close this one as duplicate.