# How to convert Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send> to Box<dyn Error>

Tags: rust

In my program some actions are performed on secondary thread and their results: `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` are sent back to primary thread. This is pretty reasonable for errors to have `Send` requirement, so the actual type is `Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send>>`. I also added `Sync` to be able to use `Box` `from` method (which is implemented for plain or Sync + Send only). But after result is settled on single thread I want to drop this requirement.

Example:

```
use std::error::Error;

fn test1() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send>> {
    return Err("test1".into());
}
fn test2() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    test1()?;
    return Ok(());
}
fn main() {
    let test2_result = test2();
    println!("test2_result: {:#?}", test2_result);
}
```

In the end I actually end with:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:7:12
  |
7 |     test1()?;
  |            ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::error::Error` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>>` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>`
  = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

It seems those types are not compatible.

So how can I convert (for example in `test2`) `Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send>>` to `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>`?

I know this can be done by creating a wrapper, but I don't want to add next level of indirection.

Comment: A `if let Err(e) = test1() { return Err(e);}` will work.

Comment: It seems that upcasting trait objects is a problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632968/why-doesnt-rust-support-trait-object-upcasting

Answer (score 1):

The question how to convert between those two types is still open.

For now I switched to https://crates.io/crates/failure crate for error handling in which `Error` type replaces `Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send>`, also making it easy to create custom and string (even formatted) errors.