# How can I downcast a dyn trait into another trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, dynamic-dispatch

I have two Rust traits, and one automatically implements the other:

```
trait A {
  fn something(&self);
}
trait B {}
impl A for dyn B {
  fn something(&self) {
    println!("hello from B")
  }
}
```

Now I receive a dynamic implementation of `B`, and I need to return a dynamic implementation of `A`:

```
fn downcast(b: Box<dyn B>) -> Box<dyn A> {...}
```

**How can I implement `downcast`?**

Some things I've tried:

1. I tried to let Rust figure it out statically:

```
fn downcast(b: Box<dyn B>) -> Box<dyn A> {
  b
}
```

This gives something like

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
expected trait `A`, found trait `B`
```

2. I tried the same static thing using `as` or an intermediate variable.
3. I tried dynamically casting using `Any` and `downcast_ref`, but I couldn't get the magic right.

Comment: Do you actually need a `Box<dyn A>` or would `&dyn A` be acceptable?

Comment: Don't think its possible, but you can add a `downcast` method to `B` that returns `self as &dyn A`.

Comment: Question was closed, but here's a possible solution: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=44a12f2bfd6ebcf2fcc36912b7c50915. If you can make `Box<dyn B>` implement your trait, then an extra layer of indirection will save you. I'll post it as an answer if my reopen vote goes through.

Comment: Tl;dr the dupe: `Box<dyn B>` does not contain a pointer to the vtable of `dyn A`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632968/why-doesnt-rust-support-trait-object-upcasting for the case where `A` is a supertrait of `B` (note this is properly upcasting, not downcasting)